# Im having an issue with this error Error: call revert exception

Tags: reactjs, next.js, blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I have the following functions and many more the issue im having is sometimes these works and sometime doesnt and it return thsi error  **Error: call revert exception**    everytime with a different a function when i relaod the project  many times then it works fine after a while it does again Im using REact/nextjs i dont know what im doing exactly im sure that the contract abi is correct  as well as the user address

```
        React.useEffect(() => {
            async function getNfts() {
              if (bscNfts.length>0 && ethNfts.length>0) {
               try {
                const total = [...bscNfts, ...ethNfts];
                setTotalNfts(total);
          
            const claimedBscNfts = await claimedRewardsBsc(bscNfts);
            const claimedEthNfts = await claimedRewardsEth(ethNfts);
            const claimed = [
              ...claimedBscNfts.claimedIds,
              ...claimedEthNfts.claimedIds,
            ];
            setClaimedNfts(claimed);
            const rewardsEth = await getAvailableRewardsEth(ethNfts, contract, ethers);
            const rewardsBsc = await getAvailableRewardsBsc(bscNfts, contract, ethers);
             
            const unclaimed = [
              ...rewardsBsc.rewardedNftIds,
              ...rewardsEth.rewardedNftIds,
            ];
      
            setUnclaimedNfts(unclaimed);
           } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
           }
          }
        }
        getNfts();
      }, [bscNfts, ethNfts]);
    
    export async function getAvailableRewardsEth(idsArray, contract, ethers) {
      const availableRewards = await contract.getCurrentRewardsETH(idsArray);
      const rewardsFloatArray = availableRewards[0].map(bn =>
        parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatUnits(bn, 6))
      );
      let totalRewards = 0;
      let rewardedNftIds = [];
      for (let r = 0; r < rewardsFloatArray.length; r++) {
        const element = rewardsFloatArray[r];
        if (element > 0) {
          rewardedNftIds.push(idsArray[r]);
        }
        totalRewards += element;
      }
      return { rewardsFloatArray, totalRewards, rewardedNftIds };
    }
    
    export async function getAvailableRewardsBsc(idsArray, contract, ethers) {
      const availableRewards = await contract.getCurrentRewards(idsArray);
      const rewardsFloatArray = availableRewards[0].map(bn => parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatUnits(bn, 6)));
      let totalRewards = 0;
      let rewardedNftIds = [];
      for (let r = 0; r < rewardsFloatArray.length; r++) {
        const element = rewardsFloatArray[r];
        if (element > 0) {
          rewardedNftIds.push(idsArray[r]);
        }
        totalRewards += element;
      }
      return { rewardsFloatArray, totalRewards, rewardedNftIds };
    }
    
      
      export async function claimedRewardsBsc(tokenIds){
        const claimedOnBsc = await contract.getTotalRewardsClaimed(tokenIds);
        const claimedOnBscFloatArray = claimedOnBsc.map(bn => parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatUnits(bn, 6)));
        //console.log(claimedOnBscFloatArray);
        let totalRewards = 0;
        for (let r = 0; r < claimedOnBscFloatArray.length; r++) {
            const element = claimedOnBscFloatArray[r];
            totalRewards += element;
        }
        return { claimedOnBscFloatArray, totalRewards };
    }
    
    
    
      export async function claimedRewardsEth(tokenIds, userAddress, contract) {
        const claimedOnEth = await contract.getTotalRewardsClaimedEth(tokenIds);
        const claimedOnEthFloatArray = claimedOnEth.map(bn =>
          parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatUnits(bn, 6))
        );
        //console.log(claimedOnEthFloatArray);
        let totalRewards = 0;
        for (let r = 0; r < claimedOnEthFloatArray.length; r++) {
          const element = claimedOnEthFloatArray[r];
          totalRewards += element;
        }
        return { claimedOnEthFloatArray, totalRewards };
      }
```

Example of Full Error:

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getCurrentRewards(uint256[])", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.js:224:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.js:233:1)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.js:345:1)
    at Contract.eval (index.js:293:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.js:5:43)
```

Comment: if you are connected to infura node or any other third party node, that node might be down